# How do I extract data from a Bokeh ColumnDatasource

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I was trying to avoid using a ColumnDataSource and instead of that I was passing pandas dataframe columns directly to Bokeh plots.

Soon though I had to implement a HoverTool which requires to have the data in a ColumnDataSource. So, I started using ColumnDataSource.

Now, I was creating a box annotation and I had to use the maximum value of a certain column from my data to define the top border of the box.

I can do that easily using pandas:

```
low_box = BoxAnnotation(
    top=flowers['petal_width'][flowers['species']=='setosa'].max(),
    fill_alpha=0.1, fill_color='red')
```

But I can't figure out how to extract the maximum from a ColumnDataSource.

Is there a way to extract a maximum value from it, or is my approach all wrong in the first place?

Comment: sorry are you asking for `top=flowers.loc[flowers['species']=='setosa','petal_width'].max()[0]`?

Comment: @EdChum I am able to extract the maximum from a pandas dataframe. I am just trying to figure out how to do the same from a bokeh ColumnDataSource which is the object that Bokeh uses to store data: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference/models/sources.html#ColumnDataSource

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A ColumnDataSource object has an attribute `data` which will return the python dictionary used to create the object in the first place.

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource

# define ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
        desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    )
)

# find max for variable 'x' from 'source'
print( max( source.data['x'] ))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the source input is a Pandas DataFrame, you can use the Standard method:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data= pd.DataFrame( dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
        desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    ))
)
print( source.data['x'].max() )
```