# How to extract a subset of ColumnDataSource in bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

The question is in the title:
how to extract a subset of ColumnDataSource in bokeh ?
Thanks.
David

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for slicing the rows this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693444/how-do-i-extract-data-from-a-bokeh-columndatasource?rq=1) might guide you and then you can apply regular Python slicing notation on the accessed result.